# How to open photos using Windows Photo software

Tags: windows-10, photos

How do I associate Windows Photos with jpeg files?
My photos won't open.
Am using Panasonic on sim card

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/225844/how-to-make-windows-photo-viewer-your-default-image-viewer-on-windows-10/

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the file and then choose 'open with', then choose Windows Photos. If you want it to be the default program you open jpeg files with, remember to check the 'always open with this program' box.

Alternatively, you could go into the control panel, look for 'default programs', click on it and then click on 'associate a file or protocol with a program' and then find .jpeg, select it and then click on 'change program'. You know what to do from there.

You can also do this for other file types.